# get innertext of user and password using angular protactor

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, protractor, karma-jasmine

I am very new in angular protractor test. I have created a small automated test for getting username and password. In html class I created id to easily identify the attributed from test class. Hence the username and password is generated from model class for examaple credentials.login for user name and credentials.password for password. I would like to get the username demo amd password demo to pass the test. But I am not getting the value from this code.

Here is my code

HTML Class

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input id="t-username" matInput [(ngModel)]="credentials.login" name="login" placeholder="{{ 'username'}}">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field class="md-block">
    <input id="t-password" matInput type="password" [(ngModel)]="credentials.password" name="password" placeholder="{{ 'password'}}" maxlength="100">
</mat-form-field>
```

and my protactor testing class

```
it('Login failed', async () => {
    //1.
    var usernameField = await element(by.id('t-username'));
    usernameField.sendKeys('demo');
    //await expect(usernameField.getAttribute('value')).toBe("demo");

    //2.
    var passwordField = element(by.id('t-password'));
    passwordField.sendKeys("demo");
    //await expect(passwordField.getAttribute('#t-password')).toBe('demo');
});
```

Comment: Does it get the username successfully? Why not `.getAttribute('value')` for the password field as well?

Answer (score 0):

The are some issue in your code, try below one:

```
it('Login failed', async () => {
    //1.
    var usernameField = element(by.id('t-username'));
    await usernameField.sendKeys('demo');
    await expect(usernameField.getAttribute('value')).toBe("demo");

    //2.
    var passwordField = element(by.id('t-password'));
    await passwordField.sendKeys("demo");
    await expect(passwordField.getAttribute('value')).toBe('demo');
});

// disable protractor control flow in conf.js
// protractor conf.js
exports.config = {
   ....
   SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false, // it's very important if you use async/wait
}
```